# Severe Lag/Stuttering on New Versions (18.10-19.04) with Vega 64

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, mesa

I'm writing this because I'm having some pretty severe issues with my system that I had originally dismissed as a card issue (patching the firmware at one point actually mitigated the issue I'm having), but doesn't seem to be a hardware/firmware issue at all now (bought another card and the same issue occurs, nothing has been touched.). In 18.04 and previous versions, I boot up, install, everything just fine. Performance is off the charts as you'd expect from these cards, but when it comes to either a) new MESA versions, or b) newer kernels (eg. straying from 4.15), my system seems to run at a rather slow grind. Moving windows around the screen is jumpy and delayed, like it's happening at 5FPS. CPU usage is low as it should be, nothing taking up cycles, but anything graphical just lags really badly. In 18.04(.1) this isn't an issue at all without updating the kernel or MESA, but when I install 18.10 or newer versions like the 19.04 daily-live images, this issue is present and makes the system unusable. I'm not quite sure where to file for this as I don't know exactly what causes the issue, but now that I know it's not specific to my card itself, I need to figure this out, otherwise I just won't be able to use Ubuntu in the future (which is a bit of a worry!). I notice that this affects Ubuntu derivatives as well for me, and is even present in other systems where (I would assume) newer kernels or MESA stacks are used.

If anyone has any ideas on what to do about this or has seen it solved/reported elsewhere, I'd love to know. I can provide additional system details as well.

For additional info about this and the associated bug report, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1815510

Comment: Did you make any progress? I'm having the same issues.

Comment: @Anthony I'm having the same issues still. It seems that running any kernel v4.18 and newer, I see this issue. But if I install a v4.17 kernel or older there's no issue. This is a severe bug though and something that means I can't run a system with an up to date and secure kernel, and I'll also slowly end up with a system incompatible with newer software :(

Comment: I formatted and installed 19.04 as a fresh install. Some things definitely improved, but the GUI is unfortunately still very laggy in many applications.